# Chapter titles distance

Tags: spacing, sectioning, titlesec

I am using the titlesec package to adjust the chapter titles/headings of my text. Yet, I have trouble with the resulting distance between these new titles and the body of the text. Namely, the distance becomes substantially smaller than what it is when no adjustment is made, i.e., chapter titles are the default ones.

I have noted that this decreament of the distance, probably has to do with the text body moving "upwards".

Here is what I have compiled:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[namelimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage[mathcal]{euscript}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[textheight=630pt]{geometry}
\topmargin -0.1in
\setlength{\headheight}{14.71pt}
\parskip=3pt
\addtolength{\parindent}{2pt}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
       {\bfseries\Large}
       {\filright\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \Huge\thechapter}
       {.5ex}
       {\titlerule[.1ex]\filleft}


\begin{document}
\chapter*{Introduction}
     \blindtext[3]
     \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Any ideas of how to restore this distance back to the default? The titlesec documentation is not of great help (to me at least) on this issue.

Comment: Look for the `\titlespacing` command in `titlesec`. A tip: don't load `graphics` and remove the `dvips` option from `graphicx`.

Comment: The answer to your question can be found in section 9.2. of the `titlesec` manual.

Comment: As well, once you load `geometry`, why don't use all its options to specify the page dimensions? Like `\usepackage[textheight=630pt, headheight=14.71pt, tmargin=0.9in, includehead]{geometry}` (And please take my and @egreg's comments as friendly advices, we're just wanting to make your LaTeX life a bit easier `;)` )

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I did incorporate them. Also, I hadn't seen this version of the titlesec manual which, on 9.2 gives the commands for the standard classes. Yet, it does not seem to solve the problem, unless I am just doing something silly.

I added to my code the line

`\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{50pt}{40pt}`

(since it seems the only relevant; Ihave not adjusted sections, subsections etc.) but the problem persists.

Comment: If you do `\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{80pt}{50pt}`, is it better?

Comment: Okay, I got the picture. I will play along with the values manually. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use

```
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{80pt}{50pt}
```

and modify the values as you wish.